# Remove last item from product collection

Tags: collection, magento-1

I want to remove last item from product collection

> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

But I have to avoid any 'loop' solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without context, I cannot say if this is a good idea, but if you have a **loaded** collection and want to remove the last item from the collection (not delete it), you can do this:

```
$lastId = $collection->getLastItem()->getId();
$collection->removeItemByKey($lastId);
```

This works because internally the items are stored in an array with their id as key.

Answer (score 2):

Additional database query but retaining collection:

```
$collection     = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(--$collectionSize);
```

Basic PHP but out of collection scope:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products   = $collection->getItems();
array_pop($products);
```